# Objective C reference to class implementing an protocol

Tags: objective-c

How to reference to a class (not an instance of it!) which implements a specific protocol?

```
+(id<Data>) dataForName:(NSString *)name {
    id<DataManager> manager = SpecializedDataManager; // <-- which datatype does "manager" have to be?
    return [[manager sharedManager] get:name]; //Getting data over a singleton of manager
}
```

Where `Data` and `DataManger`are protocols and `SpecializedDataManager` is a class implementing the `DataManager` protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this myself, but you *should* be able to use a pointer-to-class, although I doubt that you could specify that the class must implement a certain protocol:

```
static Class manager = NULL;

+ (void)someInitMethod
{
    manager = [SpecializedDataManager class];
    NSAssert([manager conformsToProtocol:@protocol(DataManager)], @"Achtung!"); 
}
```

Comment: The code shown in my first post is simplified to show the problem in a less complex manner. The "manager" variable is in fact used at many places in my code. So I have to find a way to specify the class one time and than use it as placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correct you want to write something like this:

```
id<SomeProtocol> someObject = AnotherObjectConformingThisProtocol;    
Class class = [(NSObject*)SomeObject class];

if ([someObject isKindOfClass:[AnotherObjectConformingThisProtocol class]]) {}
if (class == [AnotherObjectConformingSomeProtocol class]) {}
```

If no - please clarify what exactly do you mean.

UPDATE: I've read your comment near another post and got it:

Create wrapper classes for your DataManager and Data protocols:

```
@interface DataClass : NSObject <Data>
@end

@interface DataManagerClass : NSObject <DataManager>
@end
```

And use code like this:

```
+(DataClass*) dataForName:(NSString *)name {
    DataManagerClass* manager = SpecializedDataManager; // <-- which datatype does "manager" have to be?
    return [[manager sharedManager] get:name]; //Getting data over a singleton of manager
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for:

```
+(id<Data>) dataForName:(NSString *)name {
    Class<DataManager> manager = [SpecializedDataManager class];
    return [[manager sharedManager] get:name];
}
```